# Code is not running, or running all at once

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to create a small story on python using tkinter.
I have completed one part of it with the help of someone on this website, but now, after i allow the user to make a choice, it shows what happened to them but does not continue with the story. Or, if i put window.mainloop() at the complete end of the whole program, it shows all of the choices at once, even though the user is meant to have their choice and AFTER their first choice the second option comes.

```
# Create the Tkinter window and set the title
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("choice")

# Create a button for the options
fire = tk.Button(window, text="Make a fire",command=lambda: showSelection('a'))
fire.pack()

food = tk.Button(window, text="Find food",command=lambda: showSelection('b'))
food.pack()

sleep = tk.Button(window, text = "Go to sleep",command=lambda: showSelection('c'))
sleep.pack()

# Create a label to display the options
survive_label = tk.Label(window, font=("Arial", 12), text="")
survive_label.pack()  
# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
#AFTER THE ABOVE PART THE CODE STOPS RUNNING

print("the only option you have is to a) run or b) stay where you are. ")
print("the figure does not know you are there.")
print("If you run, you are risking the figure chasing you - and you don't know how fast it runs - it could kill you")
print("If you stay still - you are risking the figure finding out you are there, and possibly killing you")
```

I thought window.mainloop() was the problem so i moved it to the complete end of the program, but as mentioned it started to show all of the options all at once - like before the user even chooses whether they want food or sleep, it moves on to printing the fact that they either have to run or stay still.
I tried importing time as well, but that does not work either. I deleted the code and cant remember what it was before sadly, but it was something like i made a variable and made it True,  and then i had a function before which was going to tell the user about the option they picked. In that function i made the same variable be False, and then after the code that i showed, at the part where the code stops running, i said that while the variable is not false, add one second to wait until the next code plays.

Comment: I don't see anything that shows the "run" or "stay" options, just three buttons for making fire, finding food, or going to sleep.

Comment: i was more trying to say that none of the program was working after the specific part, so i only included a little bit from where it stopped working :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to be able to pick some choices with a "choice" function.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def choice(choices, description = "Choose an option:"):
    def submit(selected_choice):
        window.selected = selected_choice
        window.quit()

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Choice Picker")

    label = tk.Label(window, text=description)
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    for choice in choices:
        button = tk.Button(window, text=choice, command=lambda c=choice: submit(c))
        button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    window.mainloop()

    chosen_option = window.selected
    window.destroy()

    return chosen_option

options = ["Make a fire", "Find food", "Go to sleep"]
chosen_option = choice(options, description = "What do you choose to do?")
print(f"Chosen option: {chosen_option}")
print("the only option you have is to a) run or b) stay where you are. ")
print("the figure does not know you are there.")
print("If you run, you are risking the figure chasing you - and you don't know how fast it runs - it could kill you")
print("If you stay still - you are risking the figure finding out you are there, and possibly killing you")
chosen_option_2 = choice(["stack overflow", "is cool"])
```

Comment: well, it certainly does work exactly how i had hoped, but i dont understand the code because im not that advanced :( . is there no way at all to do it without class/object. thanks for the help!

Comment: @user Actually, you can do this without object oriented programming. I've edited my answer. :)

Comment: i have a few questions:
what is this piece of code doing:

def choice(choices, description = "Choose an option:"):
    def submit(selected_choice):
        window.selected = selected_choice
        window.quit()
and why is there a for loop. THANKS so much for the help though, i think i will be using this.

Comment: @user The ```submit``` function is a function that exists within the ```choice``` function. It makes it so that you can define the ```selected``` attribute of the window, then exit the window after. After the window exits, it runs the code after the ```window.mainloop()``` part, returning the ```chosen_option```. The for loop is to iterate over the choices and create their buttons. And no problem, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` `case` statement in Python is more powerful and allows for more complicated pattern matching.

- Create `showSelection` function. Add argument data.
- Add `Label` widget. Use .config inside `showSelection` functi
- The `root.mainloop()` is always at bottom.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("choice")

def showSelection(data):
    match data:
        case 'a':
            label.config(text="the figure does not know you are there.")
        case 'b':
            label.config(text="If you run, you are risking the figure chasing you - and you don't know how fast it runs - it could kill you")  
        case 'c':
            label.config(text="If you stay still - you are risking the figure finding out you are there, and possibly killing you")



label = tk.Label(window, text=f"the only option you have is to a) run or b) stay where you are. ")
label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

# Create a button for the options
fire = tk.Button(window, text="Make a fire", command=lambda: showSelection('a'))
fire.pack()

food = tk.Button(window, text="Find food", command=lambda: showSelection('b'))
food.pack()

sleep = tk.Button(window, text = "Go to sleep", command=lambda: showSelection('c') )
sleep.pack()

# Create a label to display the options
survive_label = tk.Label(window, font=("Arial", 12), text="")
survive_label.pack()  
# Start the Tkinter event loop
 
#AFTER THE ABOVE PART THE CODE STOPS RUNNING

#print("the only option you have is to a) run or b) stay where you are. ")
#print("the figure does not know you are there.")
#print("If you run, you are risking the figure chasing you - and you don't know how fast it runs - it could kill you")
#print("If you stay still - you are risking the figure finding out you are there, and possibly killing you")


if __name__=="__main__":
 window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]